# How to fetch data from an API from GSX2JSON?

Tags: javascript, get, fetch-api

I have this link I generated with [GSX2JSON](http://gsx2json.com/), and it looks like this: http://gsx2json.com/api?id=136PcbZppJfCH1vbE_j4X803umxv0_EWEg5Tjxnvvp7o&sheet=1. Now, I want to fetch the data into a variable, and so I used this code:

```js
async function deetdeet(){

let response = await fetch('http://gsx2json.com/api?id=136PcbZppJfCH1vbE_j4X803umxv0_EWEg5Tjxnvvp7o&sheet=1');

if (response.ok) {
  let json = await response.json();
    console.log(json)
    console.log("hyeet")
} else {
  alert("Err: " + response.status);
}
}

deetdeet()
```

Sadly, this doesn't seem to return the JSON that is shown in the API, and I can't figure out why. I've tried using `fetch()` and even `.getJSON()` from JQUERY all to no avail. Is there an issue with my code, or the API I'm using?

Comment: Are you calling the API from a https context? Most browsers block any mixed content.

Comment: Exactly the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure if you are running your site off HTTPS, that all `fetch()` requests are being handled through HTTPS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers block mixed content to protect against various attacks on users, so fetching HTTP resources from a HTTPS context will be blocked.

Look into proxying your request with a HTTPS API-Wrapper or using an API supporting HTTPS.